# Get Google Map snapshop

Tags: php, google-maps, yandex-maps

I have an Excel file with one of the fields being an address. I want for every row of the Excel to create a Word document.

One of the fields is the address. Can I use the address to generate a static view of the map and use it as an image in Word? I can't find any map APIs that have this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro).

Example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New%20York,%20Central%20Park&zoom=14&scale=2&size=400x200

[image: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New%20York,%20Central%20Park&zoom=14&scale=2&size=400x200]